# Check if all children input fields have a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if all input-fields of the same row have a value after changing a input:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$(this).find('input').each (function() {

});
```

So if all input fields have a value I want to send true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
var valid = true;
$(this).find('input').each (function() {
  if ($(this).value().length == 0) {
    valid = false;
  }
});
```

Will that work?

**EDIT**

Heres a fiddle with my code and how it works; https://jsfiddle.net/3748str4/ - note that the event is on 'change' which means you need to click OUT of the field to fire the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like so:

```
var nInputs = $('input', this).length,
    nVals   = $('input', this).filter(function() {
        return !!this.value.trim();
    }).length;
if( nVals === nInputs ) {
    //all inputs have values;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#check').on('click', function() {
        $('tr').each(function(i,v) {
            console.log( 'Row ' + i );
            var inputs = $('input', this),
                nVals = inputs.filter(function() { return !!this.value.trim(); }).length;
            if( nVals === inputs.length ) {
                console.log( 'All inputs have values' );
            } else {
                console.log( nVals + '/' + inputs.length + ' have values' );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```